# Time series - correlation and lag time

Tags: python, statistics, time-series, correlation

I am studying the correlation between a set of input variables and a response variable, price. These are all in time series.

1) Is it necessary that I **smooth out the curve** where the input variable is cyclical (autoregressive)? If so, how?

2) Once a correlation is established, I would like to quantify exactly how the input variable affects the response variable. 
Eg: "Once X increases >10% then there is an 2% increase in y 6 months later."

Which python libraries should I be looking at to implement this - in particular to **figure out the lag time between two correlated occurrences**?

Example: 
[image]

I already looked at: [statsmodels.tsa.ARMA](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/examples/notebooks/generated/tsa_arma.html) but it seems to deal with predicting only one variable over time. In [scipy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cov.html) the covariance matrix can tell me about the correlation, but does not help with figuring out the lag time.

Comment: Realizing that this is more of a statistics question than a python programming question, I am also seeking help in CrossValidated. Will post here again when I figure out the answer!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While part of the question is more statistics based, the bit about how to do it in Python seems at home here. I see that you've since decided to do this in R from looking at your question on Cross Validated, but in case you decide to move back to Python, or for the benefit of anyone else finding this question:

I think you were in the right area looking at statsmodels.tsa, but there's a lot more to it than just the ARMA package:

http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/tsa.html

In particular, have a look at statsmodels.tsa.vector_ar for modelling multivariate time series. The documentation for it is available here:

http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/vector_ar.html

---

The page above specifies that it's for working with stationary time series - I presume this means removing both trend and any seasonality or periodicity. The following link is ultimately readying a model for forecasting, but it discusses the Box-Jenkins approach for building a model, including making it stationary:

http://www.colorado.edu/geography/class_homepages/geog_4023_s11/Lecture16_TS3.pdf

You'll notice that link discusses looking for autocorrelations (ACF) and partial autocorrelations (PACF), and then using the Augmented Dickey-Fuller test to test whether the series is now stationary. Tools for all three can be found in statsmodels.tsa.stattools. Likewise, statsmodels.tsa.arma_process has ACF and PACF.

The above link also discusses using metrics like AIC to determine the best model; both statsmodels.tsa.var_model and statsmodels.tsa.ar_model include AIC (amongst other measures). The same measures seem to be used for calculating lag order in var_model, using select_order.

---

In addition, the pandas library is at least partially integrated into statsmodels and has a lot of time series and data analysis functionality itself, so will probably be of interest. The time series documentation is located here:

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html

Comment: to add to this: the VAR methods also provide impulse response functions, which are in general the main tool to look at the time path for how the variables in a system respond to shocks including across variables.