# Python - lagged regressions in time series

Tags: python, scikit-learn, time-series, regression

I'm a newbie to forecasting using Python and Scikit-learn and looking for some guidance here.

I have one dataset, which is stored in an array called "predictor".
I have another dataset, which is stored in an array called "to_be_predicted".

I know that the values in "predictor" can predict the values in "to_be_predicted" with considerable efficiency using the right regression, however I'm not sure on which anticipation the "predictor" best predicts "to_be_predicted", in other words, what is the lag between "predictor" and "to_be_predicted". Could be 1, 2, 3, 100, 1000 periods, I just don't know it.

To find that out, I could make one regression for each period of anticipation in a determined range and use some error measure on each regression to find out which is the best anticipation.

My question is: is there any library with a function that goes after the best lag between two time series?

Comment: Are you restricted to just one predictor? Why can't both lag(3) and lag(10) be predictors?

Comment: They could, but I have almost 50 "main predictors" with approx. 500 items each. If I apply 30 lags on each it will be 750.000 items to process, which I'm afraid its a lot for my macbook air, and also I will be restricted to a max of 30 lags. That's why I want to know if there is any library with a function to identify the best lag :)

Comment: A first step would be to look at the [cross-correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation#Time_series_analysis) of the two time series. A related [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25320773/time-series-correlation-and-lag-time) suggested to look at the [statsmodels.tsa](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/tsa.html) package